How can I access my applications on my microk8s from other machines on the network via subdomains?
Accessing my microk8s via subdomains
I have a MicroK8s v1.29.0 revision 6364 installed on my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS machine, I would like to access my applications via subdomains, I have the following scenario:

Two applications: myapp1 and myapp2
Two Services pointing to each of them:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
 app: myapp1
 name: myapp1
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 80
 protocol: TCP
 targetPort: 8080
 selector:
 app: myapp1
 type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
 app: myapp2
 name: myapp2
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 80
 protocol: TCP
 targetPort: 8080
 selector:
 app: myapp2
 type: ClusterIP

and Two ingess pointing to the services:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 labels:
 app: myapp1
 name: myapp1.localhost
spec:
 ingressClassName: public
 rules:
 - host: myapp1.localhost
 http:
 paths:
 - path: /
 pathType: Prefix
 backend:
 service:
 name: myapp1
 port:
 number: 80
 - host: myapp1.my-hostname
 http:
 paths:
 - path: /
 pathType: Prefix
 backend:
 service:
 name: myapp1
 port:
 number: 80
 - host: myapp1.my-hostname.local
 http:
 paths:
 - path: /
 pathType: Prefix
 backend:
 service:
 name: myapp1
 port:
 number: 80
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
 name: myapp2
 labels:
 app: myapp2
spec:
 ingressClassName: public
 rules:
 - host: myapp2.localhost
 http:
 paths:
 - path: /
 pathType: Prefix
 backend:
 service:
 name: myapp2
 port:
 number: 80
 - host: myapp2.my-hostname
 http:
 paths:
 - path: /
 pathType: Prefix
 backend:
 service:
 name: myapp2
 port:
 number: 80
 - host: myapp2.my-hostname.local
 http:
 paths:
 - path: /
 pathType: Prefix
 backend:
 service:
 name: myapp2
 port:
 number: 80

When I access the following URLS, it works perfectly:
http://myapp1.localhost/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html
http://myapp2.localhost/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html
However, this only works when I'm on my local machine, but when I access it from another machine on the network, I can't:
http://myapp1.my-hostname.local/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html
http://myapp2.my-hostname.local/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html
I receive the following error:
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
however, when I access:
http://my-hostname.local/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html
the application responds perfectly, but the myapp1 application responds
The other machines on my network can normally access this machine via hostname, including the microk8s dashboard:
https://my-hostname.local:10443/
How can I make other machines access my applications via subdomains?
example:
http://app1.my-hostname.local/
http://app2.my-hostname.local/
I tried to install microk8s metallb with the machine's IP, but nothing changed.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN means that myapp1.my-hostname.local cannot be resolved by DNS, hence this is a network issue, not a microk8s issue.
You can use curl with host-header for verifying that your config works from clients in your network.
curl -H "Host: app1.my-hostname.local" http://my-hostname.local

I believe your options are:

If you have an Asus router that supports asuswrt-merlin, configure dnsmasq to resolve your addresses
Set up a local DNS server, e.g. dnsmasq and make that the primary DNS server in your router
Register a domain/sub-domains and configure port forwarding in your router
Update /etc/hosts on all clients


Yes, I've come to the conclusion that I need to either modify all clients or set up a DNS server on my network. For testing purposes alone, I'll adopt another strategy. Thank you
